# How to create edit/update form

Tags: forms, entity-framework, symfony, symfony-2.0

I try make edit form in Symfony

```
public function editAction()
{
  $id      = 5;
  $em      = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $request = $this->get('request');
  $entity  = $em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients')->find($id);
  $form    = $this->createForm(new \Surgery\PatientBundle\Form\PatientsType(), $entity);
  $form->bindRequest($request);

  return $this->render('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patient:newpatient.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));

  if($form->isValid())
  {
    //do someting
  }
  else
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

I still get empty form without data, variable `$entity` is isset. I did insert form but I can't handle with edit action. I don't want to create forms using terminal and `php app/console` because I want to know how do it.

Comment: What does the `return` do before the `$form->isValid()` ?

Comment: Read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using **symfony 2.0.x** :

You should not bind your request before sending data to the view, neither render the view before testing for submitted data (I guess you show us test code)

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id      = 5;
    $em      = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $entity  = $em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients')->find($id);
    $form    = $this->createForm(new \Surgery\PatientBundle\Form\PatientsType(), $entity);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patient:newpatient.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));
}
```